# How to animate with duration setContentOffset of collectionView?

Tags: swift, uiviewanimationtransition

I am having an issue using UIView.animate(withDuration) on a collectionView.

Here is the code I am using:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
        self.collectionView.setContentOffset(
            CGPoint(
                x: self.offsetForItem(0),
                y: self.collectionView.contentOffset.y),
            animated: false)

    }, completion: { finished in
        print("animation done")

    })
```

My problem is the following: 
If I use animated: true the animation is almost instant and if I use animated false some of the elements from my collectionView disappear.

I have search SO for a solution on this issue but while there are many asking this question no provided solution has worked for me.

Thank you!